How to make desired adjustments to this graph
Very bad programmer here, hopefully someone can help!
I have this code:
plot_alldata <- function(data){
  
  
  #make sure 'date' column is in Date type
  data$date <- as.Date(data$date)
  
  #remove all NA values from date
  data <- na.omit(data)
  
  #find the earliest and latest dates in the df
  earliest_date <- min(data$date)
  latest_date <- max(data$date)
  
  #create sequence of dates covering the entire range
  date_sequence <- seq(earliest_date, latest_date, by = "day")
  
  expanded_data <- expand.grid(loc = unique(data$loc), date = date_sequence) %>%
    left_join(data, by = c("loc","date"))
  
  expanded_data <- expanded_data %>%
    filter(!(format(date, "%m-%d") >= "06-01" & format(date, "%m-%d") <= "09-30"))
  
  

  ggplot(expanded_data, aes(x = as.factor(date))) +
    geom_rect(data = expanded_data %>%
                filter(loc == "M2"),
              aes(xmin = 0, xmax = 535, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
              fill = "gray90", alpha = 0.3, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    geom_rect(data = expanded_data %>%
                filter(loc == "M2"),
              aes(xmin = 976, xmax = 1219, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
              fill = "gray90", alpha = 0.3, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    geom_rect(data = expanded_data %>%
                filter(loc == "M1"),
              aes(xmin = 0, xmax = 975, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
              fill = "gray90", alpha = 0.3, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    geom_rect(data = expanded_data %>%
                filter(loc == "Fram"),
              aes(xmin = 0, xmax = 243, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
              fill = "gray90", alpha = 0.3, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    geom_rect(data = expanded_data %>%
                filter(loc == "Fram"),
              aes(xmin = 488, xmax = 975, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
              fill = "gray90", alpha = 0.3, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    geom_rect(data = expanded_data %>%
                filter(loc == "Atwain"),
              aes(xmin = 244, xmax = 1219, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
              fill = "gray90", alpha = 0.3, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    geom_rect(data = expanded_data %>%
                filter(loc == "25E"),
              aes(xmin = 0, xmax = 262, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
              fill = "gray90", alpha = 0.3, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    geom_rect(data = expanded_data %>%
                filter(loc == "25E"),
              aes(xmin = 488, xmax = 1219, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
              fill = "gray90", alpha = 0.3, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    geom_rect(data = expanded_data %>%
                filter(loc == "12E"),
              aes(xmin = 0, xmax = 487, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
              fill = "gray90", alpha = 0.3, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    geom_rect(data = expanded_data %>%
                filter(loc == "12E"),
              aes(xmin = 732, xmax = 1219, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
              fill = "gray90", alpha = 0.3, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    geom_col(aes(y=total_presence, fill = "Presence"), width = 1, position = "stack") +
    geom_col(aes(y=total_song, fill = "Song"), width = 1, position = "stack") +
    facet_wrap(~ loc, scales = "free", ncol = 1, strip.position="right") +
    labs(x="Date", y="Total Detections")+
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,24, by = 6), limits = c(0, 24), expand = c(0.01, 0)) +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) ifelse(grepl("-01$", x), substr(month.abb[as.numeric(substr(x, 6, 7))], 1, 1), "")) +  

                 
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(panel.spacing.y = unit(0.3, "lines"),
          panel.grid = element_line(color = "white", linetype = "solid", size = 0.1),
          strip.text = element_text(hjust = 0, vjust =1, angle = 0),
          panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA))+
    guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Legend"))
}

this is what it creates
I'm already quite happy with some of the adjustments but there is still a view problems.
Firstly, I have the grid now set to 'white', because if i change this to 'gray', the grid fills up the space completely
like this
I tried the size parameter but no matter if I made this really big or really small, nothing changed. So how do I create a grid that is visible and doesnt cover the whole thing?
Second, I want to add a secondary x axis, which plots the year. So here is an example of how I'd like it to look like:
very bad recreated in paint of what i'd like to make as secondary x axis
Hope someone can help with these two things!
small example of my data frame

> dput(expanded_data[1:2, ])
structure(list(loc = c("12E", "25E"), date = structure(c(17440, 
17440), class = "Date"), total_presence = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), total_song = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), out.attrs = list(
    dim = c(loc = 6L, date = 1704L), dimnames = list(loc = c("loc=12E", 
    "loc=25E", "loc=Atwain", "loc=Fram", "loc=M1", "loc=M2"), 
        date = c("date=2017-10-01", "date=2017-10-02", "date=2017-10-03", 
        "date=2017-10-04", "date=2017-10-05", "date=2017-10-06", 
        "date=2017-10-07", "date=2017-10-08", "date=2017-10-09", 
        "date=2017-10-10", "date=2017-10-11", "date=2017-10-12", 
        "date=2017-10-13", "date=2017-10-14", "date=2017-10-15", 
        "date=2017-10-16", "date=2017-10-17", "date=2017-10-18", 
        "date=2017-10-19", "date=2017-10-20", "date=2017-10-21", 
        "date=2017-10-22", "date=2017-10-23", "date=2017-10-24", 
        "date=2017-10-25", "date=2017-10-26", "date=2017-10-27", 
        "date=2017-10-28", "date=2017-10-29", "date=2017-10-30", 
        "date=2017-10-31", "date=2017-11-01", "date=2017-11-02", 
        "date=2017-11-03", "date=2017-11-04", "date=2017-11-05", 
        "date=2017-11-06", "date=2017-11-07", "date=2017-11-08", 
        ..... 
        "date=2022-02-19", "date=2022-02-20", "date=2022-02-21", 
        "date=2022-02-22", "date=2022-02-23", "date=2022-02-24", 
        "date=2022-02-25", "date=2022-02-26", "date=2022-02-27", 
        "date=2022-02-28", "date=2022-03-01", "date=2022-03-02", 
        "date=2022-03-03", "date=2022-03-04", "date=2022-03-05", 
        "date=2022-03-06", "date=2022-03-07", "date=2022-03-08", 
        "date=2022-03-09", "date=2022-03-10", "date=2022-03-11", 
        "date=2022-03-12", "date=2022-03-13", "date=2022-03-14", 
        "date=2022-03-15", "date=2022-03-16", "date=2022-03-17", 
        "date=2022-03-18", "date=2022-03-19", "date=2022-03-20", 
        "date=2022-03-21", "date=2022-03-22", "date=2022-03-23", 
        "date=2022-03-24", "date=2022-03-25", "date=2022-03-26", 
        "date=2022-03-27", "date=2022-03-28", "date=2022-03-29", 
        "date=2022-03-30", "date=2022-03-31", "date=2022-04-01", 
        "date=2022-04-02", "date=2022-04-03", "date=2022-04-04", 
        "date=2022-04-05", "date=2022-04-06", "date=2022-04-07", 
        "date=2022-04-08", "date=2022-04-09", "date=2022-04-10", 
        "date=2022-04-11", "date=2022-04-12", "date=2022-04-13", 
        "date=2022-04-14", "date=2022-04-15", "date=2022-04-16", 
        "date=2022-04-17", "date=2022-04-18", "date=2022-04-19", 
        "date=2022-04-20", "date=2022-04-21", "date=2022-04-22", 
        "date=2022-04-23", "date=2022-04-24", "date=2022-04-25", 
        "date=2022-04-26", "date=2022-04-27", "date=2022-04-28", 
        "date=2022-04-29", "date=2022-04-30", "date=2022-05-01", 
        "date=2022-05-02", "date=2022-05-03", "date=2022-05-04", 
        "date=2022-05-05", "date=2022-05-06", "date=2022-05-07", 
        "date=2022-05-08", "date=2022-05-09", "date=2022-05-10", 
        "date=2022-05-11", "date=2022-05-12", "date=2022-05-13", 
        "date=2022-05-14", "date=2022-05-15", "date=2022-05-16", 
        "date=2022-05-17", "date=2022-05-18", "date=2022-05-19", 
        "date=2022-05-20", "date=2022-05-21", "date=2022-05-22", 
        "date=2022-05-23", "date=2022-05-24", "date=2022-05-25", 
        "date=2022-05-26", "date=2022-05-27", "date=2022-05-28", 
        "date=2022-05-29", "date=2022-05-30", "date=2022-05-31"
        ))), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
    


Does freeing also the x-axis range help? facet_wrap(~ loc, scales = "free", ncol = 1)

I tried this, see edit :) Thanks!

Can you please add a drawing of the desired result (e.g. a graph without no-data-periods) and a small example of your data?

Welcome to SO, @Lucat. Make sure your question is reprodutible with sample (or toy) data, the problematic/attempted code and the expected output. You almost done it: please, edit your question to include some sample/toy data.

I edited the post, I solved some of my existing questions and desires but now I have some new. I added a drawing of the desired result and small example of my data

Please add your sample data so it is copy/pasteable. We can't test code on your screenshot of data. dput(your_data[1:10, ]) will give copy/pasteable R code to recreate the first 10 rows of your_data, including all data class and structure information.

I'm sorry for being so slow understanding this... I tried to do what you suggested but the list of dates was too big, so i snipped some out but you get the idea hopefully. Is this helpfull?

You might try linewidth for controlling the grid lines. As for the secondary x axis, I'd suggest you make a separate plot with the same x range that just shows the boxes with years, and then combine it using the patchwork package to align the two graphs.
